# Ender 3 seemingly speeds up too much on straight long shell lines

Tags: ultimaker-cura, creality-ender-3, speed

After few good prints with my new Ender 3, I noticed that prints with longer shell straight lines (> 5 cm) have extrusion problems in the middle of those lines.

I figured that this might be because the printing speed (70 mm/s) and filament temperature (210 °C for PLA). So I increased my filament temperature about 215 °C and lowered print speed to 60 mm/s. I am using Cura v3.5.1. For the next few smaller prints everything was perfect.

Now I am printing a bigger 128 mm X 48 mm rectangular shape. In the middle of the 128mm line of the outer shell, I have signs of under extrusion. Looks like dents.

I also notice that the head is really fast during this 128 mm travel. No way ~2 seconds would take 60 mm/s to travel 128 mm. It is more like 1 second or less.

Why would my head travel at such speeds?

I am attaching my speed settings.

[image: Speed settings]

I am attaching the image of the printed piece and the defect generated.

[image: The problem generated]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your travel speed is set to 120mm/s so it would make sense the 128mm travel takes ~1 second. You most likely have combing turned on so that it doesn't not need to retract on travels. This makes it ooze plastic as it travels and would mimic underextrustion.

Comment: Interesting point. Combing is turned on indeed. You might be right. I am not sure. I have a knob on the extruder motor and seems that is extruding during the fast move. I might be wrong. I have to reprint this tomorrow and take into consideration your suggestion, so I can accept your answer. Thank you!

Comment: @sanyi After looking at the image it doesn't really look like a combing issue, although i still think it is related to the travel.

Comment: Travel speed is the speed at which the nozzle travels when it is not printing. Print speed is how fast the nozzle travels while printing. At a print speed of 60mm/s, it should take just over 2 second to complete the 128 mm side. You also have more advanced speed settings, including inner wall and outer wall settings, that should effect the time to print the side.